# Why does sublime text 2 eventually stop working and becomes unresponsive?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

I am trying to build the google homepage for an assignement and sublime text 2 was working for all the header part, but when I add the google logo image and try to resize it or move it around...it just doesnt respond. It doesn't resize the image or moves it anywhere. Why does sublime stop working like that. It has happened to me once before and I copied and pasted everything to a new file multiple times to get it to be responsive. Here are pictures of my code and I can't seem to get the google logo image to size down or move at all.

Here is the css https://i.stack.imgur.com/datt9.jpg
here is the html https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIO0D.jpg

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your CSS. The `ul` rule on line 38 is missing a closing brace (`}`). I'm sure that is not causing the issue, but it is a mistake I noticed. 

Also, please do not post pictures of your code. Copy and paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CSS problem you are having. Your text editor has nothing to do with it. Be sure to reload your browser when you make changes in Sublime as well.